# Vitest spyOn seems to have no effect testing a React component

Tags: reactjs, vite, vitest

I'm going through [this](https://mayashavin.com/articles/test-react-components-with-vitest) tutorial and I got this test with vi.spyOn function that seems to have no effect:

```
import * as useDatahooks from '../pages/TodoApp';
...
describe('Tasks', () => {
    const useDataSpy = vi.spyOn(useDatahooks, 'useData');

    it('should render the the list of tasks', () => {
        const dataWant = [
            { id: "todo-0", name: "Eat", completed: true },
        ]
    
        useDataSpy.mockReturnValue({
            tasks: dataWant,
            setTasks: vi.fn(),
        });
    

        const { getByTestId } = render(<TodoApp />);
        expect(
            getByTestId('task-list').children.length
        ).toBe(dataWant.length);
    });


});


afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
  });
```

I get:

```
AssertionError: expected 3 to be 1 // Object.is equality
```

So the problem is that it's not spying on anything instead the code is running as is:

```
export interface TodoItem {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  completed: boolean;
}


const DATA :TodoItem[] = [
  { id: "todo-0", name: "Eat", completed: true },
  { id: "todo-1", name: "Sleep", completed: false },
  { id: "todo-2", name: "Repeat", completed: false },
];
export const useData = (data: TodoItem[]) => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<TodoItem[]>(data); //<==== Its just using the data instead of injecting what I've mocked
  return { tasks, setTasks };
}

export default function TodoApp() {
  const  { tasks, setTasks } = useData(DATA);
  ...
  const taskList = tasks?.map((task) => (
    <Todo
      id={task.id}
      name={task.name}
      completed={task.completed}
      key={task.id}
      deleteTask={deleteTask}
    />
  ));
  return (

      <ul
        data-testid="task-list"
        role="list"
        className="divide-y divide-gray-200 px-4 my-4"
        aria-labelledby="list-heading">
        {taskList}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Can anyone please suggest how to spy properly?

Comment: Do not mock hooks.  Test the *behavior* through querying the DOM or through mocks of things needed to isolate your unit test, like network client behavior.

Comment: Am I not testing the behaviour? I'm testing that when an API is returning 1 item of TODO, then it appears in the DOM

Comment: You're testing the implementation which is not directly the behavior.  Effective testing that lets you refactor doesn't care "how", it cares about "what".  If the API is returning something you usually mock a network client or use something like `msw`.  If you have redux involved there is tooling to mock a store if that's appropriate , and it isn't always

Comment: I don't like that approach. I think most tests should be unit tests. In any case, do you know how to fix what I'm asking rather than using this other testing methodology you're proposing? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the hook to its own file, then you can spy on it.

The problem is currently the hook resides in the same file with the component. The component uses the hook directly without importing it, so spyOn may not work as expected.